# Erdős–Rényi model starting from non-complete graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

In the Erdős–Rényi model, they study graphs that are **complete**, i.e. to sample from $G(n,p)$ we start with the complete graph $K_n$ and leave each edge w.p. $p$ and drop the edge w.p. $1-p$. Then, they study the probable size of connected components (depending on thresholds given on $p$) etc.

Is there some known work done in a regime where the process is the same, but the initial graph is not $K_n$, but rather some other families of graphs. I am intrested in particular in families of graphs that are non homogenous in terms of the vertices' degrees, i.e. non-regular graphs and the degrees should be much smaller than $n-1$, even bounded by a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, lots of work has been done on this. Depending on if you're more of a physicist or more of a graph theorist, you might call this

- **bond percolation** on a graph $G$, where each edge of $G$ is taken to be "open" with probability $p \in [0,1]$ and "closed" otherwise. The most typical model is bond percolation in a $d$-dimensional lattice graph, but other cases are also studied.
- the **random subgraph** model, where in exactly the same way we define a random subgraph of a **host graph**. Some common notation for this is $G_p$ if we start with a graph $G$ and sample edges independently with probability $p$.

One paper that might interest you, if you're specifically curious about probable sizes of connected components, is [The giant component in a random subgraph of a given graph](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Efan/wp/subgraph.pdf) by Chung, Horn, and Lu. This paper shows that under some assumptions on the host graph, there is a critical probability at which a giant component emerges in the random subgraph.

The authors do consider "graphs which are not necessarily regular, and can be relatively sparse" but you will have to decide for yourself if their conditions are flexible enough for the application you have in mind.

Comment: The result seems to be nice, however I find it problematic that one of the assumptions of the theorem is that $\Delta=o\left(\frac{\widetilde{d}}{\sigma}\right)$, this is because $\Delta\geq \widetilde{d}$ and $\sigma$ can be constant as far as I can tell...

Comment: Yes, that is really a condition on having a small spectral gap. (For comparison, $\sigma = \frac1{n-1}$ when $G = K_n$.) Lemma $2$ in the paper tells you how the spectral gap is related to edge expansion in $G$ - and if $G$ does not have good edge expansion, then the conclusion of the theorem likely won't hold, since it will take only a few missing edges to break $G$ into several large components.